# Backbone.js model undefined after clicking around to other pages

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, model, attributes

I have a view that extends from another view with this initialize function:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.model = new geodemoModel();
  this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
  this.model.bind('change', this.pageSetup, this);
...
```

when the page is refreshed this pageSetup function works fine

```
pageSetup:function () {
  var self = this;
  console.log(this.model.total_fans);  
  if (this.oneSelect == 'All' || this.oneSelect == 'summary') {
    var viewSummary = new summaryView(this.summaryModel.attributes);
    $('#metrics-container').html(viewSummary.render().el);
  }
  if (this.oneSelect == 'All' || this.oneSelect == 'lifetime_fans') {
    var viewLifetime = new lifetimeView(self.model.total_fans.attributes.total_fans_object);
    $('#lifetimeFans').html(viewLifetime.render().el);
  } ...
```

However, when I come back to the page after clicking around I get this error in the console:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined"

I'm wondering why this happens, and what my misunderstanding of backbone is here. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: What line is the error thrown from? `var viewSummary` or `var viewLifetime`?

Comment: viewLifetime, does that mean i should use the same format as summaryView?  I don't get why it would fire an error some of the time but not others